# How to extract rows from numpy array where value in col1 = a

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, data-processing, numpy-slicing

I have a 2d array of temperature values per year, where there are a few values given for each year. So the array looks something like this:

```
[[1960, a, b, c, d, e, f ...],
 [1960, a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 ...],
 [1960, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2 ...],
 [1961, a, b, c, d, e, f ...],
 [1961, a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 ...],
 [1961, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2 ...],
 [1962, a, b, c, d, e, f ...],
 [1962, a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 ...],
 [1962, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2 ...]....]
```

I need to extract everything in the column 1 (so all the a values) for the rows where column 0 is 1961.

Does anyone know how I would go about this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let L be the your array. Then use the following code.

```
L[L[:, 1] == 1960][:, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works with regular python lists:

```py
[item[1] for item in array if item[0]==1961]
```

where `array` is your 2d input array.

Answer (score 0):

Use slicing
To select second values

```py
a[a[:, 0] == '1961', 1]
```

Or for all values

```py
a[a[:, 0] == '1961']
```